# What is the wattage here?

Tags: power

I've had to make a series for physics and now we're being made to compute for cost of electrical consumption over 2 hours

The series is as follows:

9 volt battery (standard Everready)
1000 ohms resistor
2 volt yellow LED, 20 mA maximum current
3.2 volt white LED, 20 mA maximum current
2 volt yellow LED, 20 mA maximum current
switch

How do I compute for kwh?

One person said current= 0.0018 amps because the voltage that gets to the resistor is 1.8 V (9V-2-3.2-2) and divide that by 1000 ohms. If that's the case, is power in the entire system .0018 amps * 1.8 volts? Or .0018 amps * 9 volts because the battery is 9V? Or is it .0018 amps * 7.2 Volts because the lamps are 7.2 volts total?

Or is power 7.2 V (3.2+2+2) so it's (7.2 V/1000 ohms)*7.2 V?

Or is power 9 V so it's (9 V/ 1000 ohms)*9 volts?

Or is it 7.2 V * 20mA?

Not in the textbook, I've scoured through the internet and I've phoned-a-friend and I'm nowhere near the answer

Comment: Watts/Time and Watts = Volts*Amps

Answer (score 1):

The power delivered by the battery is the battery voltage times the current delivered by the battery.

Other powers you calculated are the power dissipated in the resistor, and the power dissipated in the LEDs.

In all cases, the current you use should be the actual measured current in the circuit.  The 20 mA Absolute Maximum current rating for the LEDs is irrelevant (as long as the current in the circuit is below that value). You should actually measure the current, rather than depending on your calculations, as the actual forward voltage of the LEDs will vary somewhat with current.

By the way - we would normally say "make a series circuit", not just "make a series"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your specification mean the voltage drop over each LED the overall current will be 1.8V/1000 Ohm = 1.8 mA. Total power delivered by the battery is 9V times 1.8mA  = 16.2 mW. Energy over two hours would 16.2mW * 7200s = 116.6 J.

Comment: The calculated current would be 1.8 volts/1000 Ohms = 1.8 mA, not 18 mA.